# Scale keyframe animation speed in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, animation

Suppose I have a storyboard, created at runtime by some process, containing keyframe animations. Is it possible to "scale" the animation speed so that the animation plays faster (or slower) after it has been constructed?

I am currently trying to make the decision wether to use the built-in animation stuff or to use something like DispatcherTimer or CompositionTarget.Rendering and do the moving of objects manually. Speed control is one of the requirements I have..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. The property on the Storyboard is called "SpeedRatio"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.speedratio(v=VS.95).aspx